# Куда лучше помещать основной контент главной страницы WP?

Tags: wordpress

Куда правильнее помещать контент главной страницы в WP? Смотрю что многие закидывают основной контент в `index.php` или `home.php`, а кто-то создает отдельный файл в `template-parts/content-page__slug`(допустим `home-page`). И закидывают файлы главной страницы туда. Какой из способов технически правильный?
И еще один вопрос, допустим я помещаю контент в определенный php файл, как указать что страница в Wordpress привязывалась именно к этому файлу php?
Допустим страницы отзывы, создаю под нее отдельный php файл, и где в админке WP указать ссылку на этот php файл.

Comment: Правила SO (и вообще ФАК-сервисов): один топик - один вопрос.

Answer (score 5):

Контент в WP должен быть в базе. Пользователь должен иметь возможность редактировать этот контент из админки. Иначе смысла в CMS ровно ноль.

Не стоит начинать знакомство с WP с написания собственной темы. Вы сделаете кучу ошибок. Берите стандартную любую из [официального репозитория](https://ru.wordpress.org/themes/), создайте от неё [дочернюю](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html), и вносите в неё необходимые изменения. Так вы постепенно изучите структуру темы, способы создания разных шаблонов.

Подробнее об иерархии шаблонов WP можно прочитать [здесь](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Comment: +1. ТС, похоже с первого за не понимает :)

Comment: Да, только начал изучать. По поводу контента в базе - это понятно. Если позволите - еще один вопрос, если я буду добавлять текстовый контент и картирки\видео через ACF - это будет считаться адекватной практикой?

Comment: Через ACF - да, пользователь ведь может редактировать поля ACF

Answer (score 0):

Стандартным считается вариант на основе index.php (более подробно структуру шаблона см. в [документации](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)).

> И еще один вопрос, допустим я помещаю контент в определенный php файл, как указать что страница в Wordpress привязывалась именно к
>   этому файлу php?

Из коробки такой функционал не предусмотрен. Да и это не лучшее решение.

WordPress строит адреса на основе структуры сайта, которая прописывается в БД в виде иерархии рубрик/постов или страниц.

Если Вам нужно, чтобы адрес страницы просто заканчивался на html или php, это можно настроить в админке в разделе "Настройки"->"Постоянные ссылки" (блок "Произвольно").